# Is there a way to make scanf read from a file

Tags: c, file, file-io, scanf

I have a bunch of non-printable ASCII characters which I wanted to give as input to a program. So, I wanted to know if there is a way to provide input to scanf in C from a file.

UPDATE: fscanf is a way to read data from files, but I do not want to alter the code so is it possible to do this task using just scanf.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: No, that is not an option since I don't want to alter the program.

Comment: You have two problems now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fscanf (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/).

Alternately, you can redirect input to your program from a file.

e.g.

```
./a.out < input.txt
```